# Getting key to cross call a http trigger azure function

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

I have a time triggered function which would need to invoke another http triggered function in the same function app. I do not want to open the function as anonymous. I would want it to Auth based on function or admin key.

How do I get either master key or (better) function key in the time triggered function to cross call the http triggered function ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to put the key into App Settings of the timed function, and then read it at runtime, e.g. from `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable`.

Comment: I was thinking, since time triggered function is also part of the same function app, it should at least be able to get hold of master key.